# ExpertPDF Run JavaScript only in PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using old version of [ExpertPDF](http://www.expertpdf.net/).

I have web page and I click PDF link.

I have some JavaScript that I only want to run in the PDF window.

How do I check in JavaScript that the script will run in the PDF generated window? I am trying to hide some elements that don't need to show in the PDF.